# Unauthorized endpoint calling authorized Microservices

Tags: c#, .net, microservices

I hope this perhaps isn't too generic of a question. In gatewayAPI based microservices architecture pattern in .net - is it possible for a method dressed with [AllowAnnonymous] to call a method from another microservice that is dressed with [Authorize]?

The challenge that I have is that I have a payment processing method, which posts to another microservice to send an email confirmation, but the email method is marked authorized, and payment one is not.

Comment: Do you understand the authorization in web, in general? Http, headers, cookies bla bla...how does one method having AllowAnonymous affect the other method? ...In short, the answer is NO. Unless you have something specific for us.

Comment: @Ergis "Do you understand the authorization in web, in general? Http, headers, cookies bla bla...how does one method having AllowAnonymous affect the other method? " - obviously anonymous method can call method that requires authorization - it just need to construct one (pass-through authorization is just one way to do that). So not really sure what your "NO" relates to.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm on my phone and in my head I remembered the question as "does it affect" thats why I said NO...should be YES lol

Comment: Could I just make the email endpoint not be publicly available and not authorized ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Think of it in terms of who is making the request.

A user makes a request to your endpoint, if there's any authorization, it's processed against the user's session token, form data, other cookies, etc that were included in the request by the user's browser.

If your code spins up an HttpClient and sends a request, the 'user' in this case is your server. If authorization is required, you'll need to include that in the HttpRequestMessage. What that looks like exactly depends on the endpoint you're hitting.